# Ajax to PHP return count for each item category

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have 5 different categories of items. I need to make get the count of each item in the categories and update the count on page. I'm making an AJAX call to a PHP function which grabs the data from a MySQL table. I can get close but can't quite get it to work.

AJAX:

```
$(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url : '/getItemList.php',
    type : 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(data) {
      $(data ).each(function( key, value ) {
        console.log( key + ": " + value);
      });
    },
    error : function(request,error)
    {
      console.log(request);
    }
  });
})
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  try {    
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT itemType, count(*) from `Items` group by itemType");
        $stmt->execute();
        $results=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($results);
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
     $errorMessage =  "Sorry, something webt wrong";
  }
  $conn = null;
?>
```

Output:

> 0: [object Object]
>    1: [object Object]
>    2: [object Object]

I was hoping for more of:

> "itemCategoryOne" : 3
>     "itemCategoryTwo" : 12
>     "itemCategoryThree" : 3

Which is what is stored in [object Object] above.

Comment: What output did you get when you `var_dump($results); exit;`?

Answer (score 0):

In success call back of ajax request first you'll need to parse the data. 
Ex: JSON.parse (data).  then you can use each function on parsed item.

Comment: As far as I can tell the json_encode in my PHP is already turning it into an object. JSON.parse is giving me the error "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Answer (score 0):

`fetchAll` return array of result that key is column name and value is value of row. So you should convert it to what you want:

**Note**: for get `count(*)` in PDO, need to alias `count(*)`.

```
<?php
  try {    
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT itemType, count(*) as count from `Items` group by itemType");
        $stmt->execute();
        $results=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $response_array = array();
        foreach($results as $result)  {
            $response_array[$result['itemType']] = $result['count'];
        }

        echo json_encode($response_array);
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
     $errorMessage =  "Sorry, something webt wrong";
  }
  $conn = null;
?>
```